# Is it possible to extend Test Cases in Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, extend, nightwatch.js

Does anyone has experience with extending Test Cases in Nightwatch. 
I want to have some main Test Case and than the same Test Case to extend it with few more functions.
For example I have one Test Case which works fine on Desktop, but in order to work on Mobile device I need to click one more button,
so I want to crate new Test Case which will extend the Test Case for Desktop and than will click on the required button?I don't want to use custom commands

Answer (score 0):

I use page objects for this, where all "clicky" logic is abstracted into little functions about "user intent". That could be ideal for what you're talking about. I also use globals to inject my browser name into my test_settings in nightwatch.json so I can test on it, or include it in screenshot names. You could use this to decide whether to do your extra click.

```
...
"ie10": {
        "selenium_host": "10.20.3.161",
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "internet explorer",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
            "ie.ensureCleanSession": true
        },
        "globals": {
            "env": "ie10"
        }
    },
...
```